# utility dialog to edit JavaDoc tags and multiline-comments

Tags: java, c++, text-editor, ide, plug-in

I'm looking for a utility (either stand-alone tool or IDE plugin) that uses a dialog to do something like the mockup I created ...

[image]

Essentially what I want most is a tool that will allow me to fill-in-the-blanks for a javadoc comment, and take care of nicely formatting it. This is especially true for the paragraph multi-line comments. After that if it is smart enough to automatically extract member names to pre-populate the wizard that is a big plus. If it is open-source all the better, I would be pretty willing to help such a project in any way I can.

I would even be okay with a similar tool for other languages like C/C++ which could be forked for Java.

Answer (score 0):

The [CudaText](http://uvviewsoft.com/) editor has Python plugin API, it also can create such rich dialogs in plugin. So for sure  you can create the plugin. You can ask for help at CudaText support [forum](http://synwrite.sourceforge.net/forums/), someone can do this plugin for donation. Java syntax is supported via addon.

Comment: Preftkp: Are you talking about a plugin to create dialogs? If so that is not what I am asking for. I am asking if anyone knows of a utility to create **formatted block comments** _via_ a dialog window.

Comment: @MathewAmbrose Plugin can do both things. a) show dialog to ask user for params, b) insert JavaDoc to file.